# How to use phonegap-facebook-plugin in ionic?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I'm building an app in [ionic](http://ionicframework.com/)/[Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) in which I want my users to be able to log in using Facebook. So I'm trying to install the [PhonegapFacebookPlugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) that I found on [ngCordova.com](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/facebook/).

The first thing that I noticed was that the [docs on the ngCordova.com website](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/facebook/) for installing the plugin on Android are different from the docs on [the project's github docs](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/platforms/android/README.md). So I first tried using the (simpler) instructions on the github page first, which after installing and trying to use the following code:

```
facebookConnectPlugin.login(['email'],
    function(data){ console.log(JSON.stringify(data));},
    function(error){console.log(error);});
```

led to these errors:

```
file:///android_asset/www/lib/phonegap-facebook-plugin-master/facebookConnectPlugin.js: Line 181 : Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
file:///android_asset/www/js/app.js: Line 23 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Keyboard' of undefined
file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js: Line 19387 : TypeError: Cannot call method 'login' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.fbLogin (file:///android_asset/www/js/controllers.js:10:31)
    at $parseFunctionCall (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:20124:18)
    at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:50863:9
    at Scope.$eval (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22178:28)
    at Scope.$apply (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22276:23)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:50862:13)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10823:21)
    at triggerMouseEvent (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2811:7)
    at tapClick (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2800:3)
    at HTMLDocument.tapTouchEnd (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2918:5)
```

After running into these errors, I tried continuing with the more extensive [installation instructions on the ngCordova website](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/facebook/), but the following command:

```
android update project --subprojects --path "platforms/android" --target android-19 --library "com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/FacebookLib"
```

led to the following error:

```
Resolved location of library project to: /Users/kramer65/repos/my-app/platforms/android/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/FacebookLib
Error: Project folder '/Users/kramer65/repos/my-app/platforms/android/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/FacebookLib' is not a valid directory.
Error: No Android Manifest at: /Users/kramer65/repos/my-app/platforms/android/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/FacebookLib
```

This makes sense, because there is no folder called `com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/` in the `platforms/android/` folder. I don't really know why not though. Do I need to copy-paste it there? Or did something go wrong in a previous step?

I'm stuck here and I really need to get this working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you done this ?  https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/platforms/android/README.md you need to install the plugin first...

Comment: Read My blog, I created it knowing that many people will run into this issue...   https://snowscripter.wordpress.com/2015/02/12/cordova-facebook-plugin-issuses-and-solutions/

Comment: @aorfevre - Thanks for that. I now realise I didn't even add the FB SDK to my project (let alone generate key hashes). So starting with adding the FB SDK I'm trying to follow this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started . The problem is now that I need to edit `build.gradle` and in https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/xxx/?platform=android I need to give in Default Activity Class Name. So my question: can I edit `build.gradle` or will it be overwritten by ionic/Cordova? And what `Default Activity Class Name` should I supply to Facebook?

Comment: @KaranKumar - Thanks for your blogpost. I left a message there.. :-)